# Simple java regexp problem

Tags: java, regex

Why this code would fail?

```
assertTrue(Pattern.matches("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "abc;"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If fails because matches tries to match the complete string, your regexp matches 1 character which is not in the character ranges you list, if you change to:

```
assertTrue(Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]").matcher("abc;").find());
```

it should assert true.

Comment: It will assert true, by matching the `";"`, but I suspect that is not what the OP had in mind.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. What about if I use Pattern.matches(".*[^a-zA-Z0-9].*", "abc;")? Is it the same?

Comment: @jackysee, It would result in the same behaviour, the difference is that between finding a non-alphanumeric and checking that a string has the format "anything" "non-alphanumeric" "anything" which is not quite the same. Using the find, you could look for the next non-alpha character in your string, using matches you cannot do that for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Because the `.matches()` method tries to match the entire string, and your regex doesn't match the entire string, only the semicolon. The `Matcher.find()` method would work (in this case: find a character that is not a letter between a and z nor a number between 0 and 9. Of course, it will also find á, ö etc.)

What is it you really want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Because `Pattern.matches()` [is equivalent to](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) the corresponding pattern being compiled and fed to `Matcher.matches()` which, [as specified](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()), checks to see if the entire input matches the pattern. If you only want to match part of the input, you'll want to use `Matcher.find()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try "^[a-zA-Z0-9]" as pattern

Comment: I believe the OP is trying to match the `;` in the target string.  So it's not the regex that's wrong, it's using `matches()` instead of `find()`, as others have pointed out.  In any case, "try this instead" is not a particularly helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you put the ^ inside, it means [any char not in a-z or A-Z](http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/analyzer.html?regex=%5B%5Ea-zA-Z0-9%5D&env=env_java). What you want is [`^[a-zA-Z0-9]`](http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/analyzer.html?regex=%5E%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D&env=env_java)